# Assigning non-interpolated colors on a mesh in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to create a surface that has a color assigned to each face such that they appear as a square meshed colormap.

Currently, I can create a geometry after shameless copying some of [@LeeStemkoski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477353/lee-stemkoski)'s work and assign the color value using an array (frame), but the colors are interpolated between the faces. Is there a way I can force the colors to cover the faces between the integer values xx and xx+1, yy and yy+1? or is there a better way to generate the mesh than `THREE.ParametricGeometry`

```
for ( var i = 0; i < graphGeometry.faces.length; i++ ) 
{
    face = graphGeometry.faces[ i ];
    numberOfSides = ( face instanceof THREE.Face3 ) ? 3 : 4;
    for( var j = 0; j < numberOfSides; j++ ) 
    {
        vertexIndex = face[ faceIndices[ j ] ];
        //face.vertexColors[ j ] = graphGeometry.colors[ vertexIndex ];
            point = graphGeometry.vertices[ vertexIndex ];
                    color = new THREE.Color( 0x0000ff );
                    xx = Math.round(point.x+nx/2);
                    yy = Math.round(point.y+ny/2);
                    ii = nx*yy+xx;

                color.setHSL( 0.7 * (max - frame[ii]) / (max-min), 1, 0.5 );
                    face.vertexColors[ j ] = color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can : in that function you can see that colors are assigned per vertices (well sure you can't assign color to faces). So all you have to do is to get the average color value you use to calculate the color per face. Given faces are now all `Face3` in threejs you have to calculate it for 2 faces each time actually. From what you quoted above it gives (comment the `for` loop that comes before) :

```
for ( var i = 0; i < graphGeometry.faces.length; i+=2 ) 
{
    face1 = graphGeometry.faces[ i ];
    face2 = graphGeometry.faces[ i +1 ];
    numberOfSides = 3;
    var averageFaceZPosition=0;
    for( var j = 0; j < numberOfSides; j++ )averageFaceZPosition+= graphGeometry.vertices[face1[ faceIndices[ j ] ]].z;
    for( var j = 0; j < numberOfSides; j++ )averageFaceZPosition+= graphGeometry.vertices[face2[ faceIndices[ j ] ]].z;
    averageFaceZPosition/=numberOfSides*2;
    color=new THREE.Color(0x0000ff);
    color.setHSL( 0.7 * (zMax - averageFaceZPosition) / zRange, 1, 0.5 );
    for(var j=0;j<numberOfSides;j++){
        face1.vertexColors[j]=color;
        face2.vertexColors[j]=color;
    }
}
```

And the result :

[image]